# Non-greedy regex extraction from JSON with sed

Tags: json, regex, shell, sed, grep

Some JSON:

```json
{"theSecret":"flhiusdh4543sdfasf34sdf+fsfs/sdf43454=","foo":{"bar":41,"something":"hello world","else":"hi","date":20230101,"qux":0,"digest":"sfhusdf234jkkjuiui23kjkj/SFDF34SDSFDS="}}
```

Prettified:

```json
{
  "theSecret": "flhiusdh4543sdfasf34sdf+fsfs/sdf43454=",
  "foo": {
    "bar": 41,
    "something": "hello world",
    "else": "hi",
    "date": 20230101,
    "qux": 0,
    "digest": "sfhusdf234jkkjuiui23kjkj/SFDF34SDSFDS="
  }
}
```

I want the value of the `theSecret` key.

I tried this:

```bash
$ echo "$json" | sed -nE 's/.*theSecret":"(.*)".*/\1/p'    # (.*?) doesn't work
```

Which gives:

```
flhiusdh4543................4SDSFDS=
```

i.e. from `theSecret` until the end of `digest`. That's because sed lacks non-greedy quantifiers, so `.*?` doesn't work.

How can I do this?

(This is in an alpine container, which has `sed`, `grep` and `awk`. `jq` and `perl` are unavailable.)

Comment: Don't use regex to process JSON. Use a tool like `jq` that knows how to parse it.

Comment: @Barmar True. But this is in a container without jq.

Comment: If it lacked `?` then it wouldn't match at all.

Comment: @Barmar I read in other questions that sed lacks the non-greedy quantifier `.*?`. From my test above that seems to be the case. Have I misunderstood, or made a mistake?

Comment: Instead of non-greedy, use `[^"]*`

Comment: @Barmar "If it lacked ? then it wouldn't match at all." - no. `sed` lacks support of lazy quantifiers, but their presence doesn't break matching: it simple disregards question mark after quantifier, and proceeds with greedy one. Consider this [demo](https://ideone.com/6wljQQ)

Comment: does your grep understand `-P` and `-o`? If so and assuming the value is base64-encoded, `grep -Po '"theSecret":"\K[^"]*' <json`

Comment: with sed: `sed -n '/.*"theSecret":"/{s///;s/".*//p;}' <json`

Comment: @markalex It's very weird that it accepts them and ignores them, but I agree that it's what the behavior shows.

Comment: If you feel the duplicate closure of a question isn't correct please edit the question to **explain why the duplicate doesn't apply**. Don't add in comments about the close voter, etc. If you feel there is some problematic pattern with a particular user please **flag for moderator attention**. If you feel there is some discussion needed in the community please take it to [meta]

Comment: If you are editing the question to contest the dupe closure the **only** thing you should add is the explanation of why the target doesn't answer your question (or some clarification / information actually relevant to the question). All of the other commentary you added to your question does not belong there. Again as I mentioned if you want a discussion take it to [meta].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a non-greedy quantifier, use a pattern that doesn't match the terminating `"`.

```
$ echo "$json" | sed -nE 's/.*theSecret":"([^"]*)".*/\1/p'    # (.*?) doesn't work
```

Comment: `[^"]*` matches the longest possible sequence of non-quote characters, which necessarily has to stop before the `"` character. That character is then matched by the `"` after the capture group.

Comment: for this particular case it looks like the value is base64-encoded but, in general, this regex is broken unless you extend it to handle escaped quotes: `'{"theSecret":"mylovely\"secret\""}` eg. `.*theSecret":"(([^\\"]|\\")*)".*`

Comment: Trying to use regular expressions to parse arbitrary JSON is hopeless. It's only feasible when you know that the data is restricted like this.